# Can't play video using unity 3d in android application

Tags: android

I am trying integrate Unity 3d with android and play rotating cuebe, the problem is that when I run the application I only getting Blank activity..please help me to find any solution

```
         import android.app.Activity;
         import android.os.Bundle;
         import android.view.View;
         import android.view.WindowManager;
         import android.widget.FrameLayout;
          import android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams;
         import com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer;
        public class MainActivity extends Activity{
    //setContentView(R.layout.main);
    private UnityPlayer mUnityPlayer;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mUnityPlayer = new UnityPlayer(this);
       // mUnityPlayer.setScreenSize(300, 250, true);
        if (mUnityPlayer.getSettings ().getBoolean ("hide_status_bar", true))

            getWindow ().setFlags (WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,

                                   WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        View playview=(View)findViewById(R.id.view1);
        playview=mUnityPlayer.getView();
        int glesMode = mUnityPlayer.getSettings().getInt("gles_mode", 1);

        boolean trueColor8888 = false;
        mUnityPlayer.init(glesMode, trueColor8888); 
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        FrameLayout layout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.framelayout2);     
        LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams (LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,          LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
        layout.addView(playview, 0, lp); 
}
           @Override
          public void onBackPressed() {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          super.onBackPressed();
  }

 }
```

Comment: Please upload your code as well.

Comment: Hi edited my question with my code as u mentioned

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to extend activity with UnityPlayerActivity and also add this activity inside manifest file like `<activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.yourpackagename" >` and it should be your main activity.